# Subequations inside a table

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am trying to insert a subequation system inside a table.
This is the idea of what I want:

```
\begin{table*}[tb]
\centering
\caption{Device Modelling Specifications.}
\label{tab:deviceModelling}
%\begin{tabular}{p{2.4cm} p{1.4cm} p{1.4cm} p{1.4cm}}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}

.....

 \hline
\textbf{Fist model} & 
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a2 = b2
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
& 
....
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does it mean you're trying to squeeze several equations into a single cell in a table?

Comment: Please make your code into _complete_ documents (known as MWE) that may be run. equations have to be in `p` columns or other par-mode contexts as in your commented out line. They may not be in `c` columns which have to be one line.

Comment: We could do with an idea of what you are trying to achieve: this all sounds very odd.

Comment: @CountZero That is right, i have a table, where, in some cells I need to put different equations.

Comment: @fernandogarcía please edit your question to be a complete document and then say in what way you need the output to change, so people have a clue how they can help. As I said in my first comment equations should work in p columns but not in c or l columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[tb]
        \centering
        \caption{Device Modelling Specifications.}
        \label{tab:deviceModelling}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{2.4cm}|m{1.4cm}|m{1.4cm}|m{1.4cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Fist model} &
            {\begin{align*}
                a &= b\\
                a2 &= b2
            \end{align*}} &
            another cell & last cell\\
            \hline
            dummy & text & I & entered\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

As David Carlisle put it in his comment, you will need a *paragraph* type of cell, so `l`, `r` or `c` columns won't do. I assumed you would like to have things centered vertically, so I chose type `m` (note that this option requires the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package). If you have other preferences, instead of `m` you can use `p` (top) or `b` (bottom).

The [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package will give you the possibility to use the `align` environment, as I did in the example. You can also choose from a wide variety of environments described in the [`amsmath` documentation](http://ftp.roedu.net/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

One last thing: The entire `align` environment is put between curly braces, because otherwise LaTeX will try to expand it at the wrong moment and the document will not compile. This comes from the fact that `align` uses `&` to set the alignment points and the same character is used as a cell separator in `tabular`. Of course in an environment without ampersand (e.g. `multline`) there is no need for these braces.

Comment: I have already vote +, how to validate the answer?

Comment: done. Sorry, i had not noticed